# How to expose a range of UDP ports with Docker

Tags: docker

I've read through the documentation completely and cannot find how to open a range of UDP ports:

```
FROM some/image
EXPOSE 80 443 3478 3478/udp 10000–20000/udp #doesn't work
COPY ./mount/x.conf /etc/y.conf
```

Does anyone know how to open a port range, using UDP ports 10000–20000, in a Dockerfile?

Alternatively does anyone know how to open all TCP and UDP ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify multiple expose:

```
EXPOSE 80 
EXPOSE 443 
EXPOSE 3478/udp
EXPOSE 10000-20000/udp
```

[Read about multiple expose](https://linuxhint.com/dockerfile_expose_ports/)

Regarding opening all ports, I would suggest using host networking
No need to map the ports. All the docker container ports will be available since the network host will make the container use the host's network
[Read about host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks I'd missed this. Is it possible to set host networking in the dockerfile, or only as a command line argument?

Comment: Welcome, Im not sure about Dockerfile, However, if you want to change to run things from docker-compose it's there as "networks"